# How to disable/deactivate nginx file compression/merge?

Tags: nginx, merge, compression, plesk, pagespeed

We use PLESK and pagespeed with nginx. Now all CSS-files are compressed and merged into one single file. Like test.com/A.style.css+style2.css+plugin.css+test.css etc.

How can i disable that file compression for development in PLESK with additional nginx commands or something? I want to use nginx but without merging of CSS-files.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Pagespeed uses gzip compression, so you can just disable it completely using directive:

```
gzip off;
```

Or specify the `gzip_types` values without `text/css` files.
Check the module description [here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_gzip_module.html).
In case you manage website configuration in Plesk, you can add additional nginx directives in Plesk > Subscriptions > example.com > Apache & Nginx Settings > Additional nginx directives.